# Best practices for creating a two dimensional array of std::strings

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am new to c++ and learning how to declare, use and delete a two dimensional array of std::string.

Because this is a learning exercise I am ignoring the idea of using vectors (for now).

I wrote a program that creates a small two dimensional array, adds data and then deletes the 2d array trying to use best practices along the way.

Can someone suggest improvements?  I am most concerned about cleaning up the 2d array after I'm done using it, so I can avoid the possibility of a memory leak.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void DIM(std::string **marray,unsigned int row,unsigned long cols)
{
    if (marray[row] != nullptr) {
        delete [] marray[row];
        marray[row] = nullptr;
    }
    marray[row] = new std::string[cols];
}

void DIM_DELETE (std::string **marray,unsigned int row)
{
    if (*&marray[row] != nullptr) {
        delete[] marray[row];
        marray[row] = nullptr;
    }
}

void DIM_DELETE_ALL (std::string **marray,unsigned int rows)
{

    for (int i=(rows-1); i>-1; i--) {
        if (marray[i] != nullptr) {
            delete[] marray[i];
            marray[i] = nullptr;
        }
    }//next i
//now take care of marray
    if (marray != nullptr) {
        delete [] marray;
        marray = nullptr;
    }
}

std::string **create2darray(unsigned int rows,unsigned int cols)
{
//first create the pointer
    std::string **my = nullptr; //create pointer , note: no data portion assigned yet

//now assign a data portion to the pointer (could do above in one step)
    my = new std::string*[rows];// elements 0 through rows-1 //assigns data section (an array of std::strings)

//now set newly created rows to nullptr
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<rows; i++) {
        my[i] = nullptr;
    }

//dim each row for cols columns
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<rows; i++) {
        DIM(my,i,cols);//dims the strings (creates data portion) my = new std::string*[x];//
    }

    return my;//returning a std::string **
}

int main()
{

    unsigned int rows = 3;//3 rows (0 through 2)
    unsigned int cols = 4;//4 columns (0 through 3)

    std::string **myarray = create2darray(rows,cols);//2d array (3 rows, 5 cols)
    cout << "2d array created" << endl << endl;
    myarray[0][0] = "a0"; //row 0, col 0
    myarray[1][0] = "b0"; //row 1, col 0
    myarray[2][0] = "c0";
    myarray[0][1] = "a1";
    myarray[0][2] = "a2";
    myarray[0][3] = "a3";
    myarray[1][1] = "b1";
    myarray[1][2] = "b2";
    myarray[1][3] = "b3";
    myarray[2][1] = "c1";
    myarray[2][2] = "c2";
    myarray[2][3] = "c3";
    cout << "assigned data to rows 0 to 2 and cols 0 to 3" << endl << endl;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        cout << i << ",0: " << myarray[i][0] << " " << i << ",1: " << myarray[i][1] << " " << i << ",2: " << myarray[i][2] <<  " " << i << ",3: " << myarray[i][3] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "we are done with 2d array, let's delete it" << endl;
//tested dim_delete (seems to work)
    /*
    DIM_DELETE(myarray,0);//delete [] myarray[0]; myarray[0] = nullptr;
    DIM_DELETE(myarray,1);
    DIM_DELETE(myarray,2);
    //still need to delete myarray
    delete [] myarray;
    myarray = nullptr;
    */

//delete all rows and delete the std::string that holds the rows
    DIM_DELETE_ALL(myarray,rows);
    cout << "array deleted, all done" << endl;

//hold cursor so user can see console messages
    do {} while(cin.get()!='\n');
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I recommend you never use `new`.  Instead use `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique`, or use `std::vector`.  If you need a 2-D array, make a class that internally has a 1-D `std::vector` that is rows * cols big, and make a `std::string operator()(size_t row, size_t col) const` getter.

Comment: The best way to avoid a memory leak is to make it logically impossible to leak memory. It will be logically impossible to leak memory when no memory is `new`ed in the first place, don't you agree? Pretty hard to leak memory when there is no memory to leak. If so, then simply replace all your `new`s and `delete`s with `std::vector`, which handles all the memory allocation for you, and then you don't have to worry about any pesky memory leaks. That's what `std::vector` is all, after all. That's it's job.

Comment: If you want to really do this by hand, I suggest you take the time to write a properly built, home-made `vector` class, preferably a template class.  You learn basically nothing by writing code in the way you wrote it, since no one, at least that has experience, writes code this way.  At least if you make your own class, you're learning how to properly allocate/deallocate memory, how to write a class with correct copy semantics, etc. Otherwise if you want to skip all of that, then use `std::vector`, as everyone else has stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the second dimension of your array is constant, I think you can be fine using a single new and delete operators. Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

int ROWS = 3;
const int COLS = 4;

typedef std::string arr4[COLS];

int main()
{
        arr4 *a;

        a = new arr4[ROWS];

        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
          for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            a[i][j] =  std::to_string(j*ROWS + i);

        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        {
          for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
             printf("%s ", a[i][j].c_str());
          printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");

        delete [] a;
}
```